# Get Sum of 2nd <td> in every <tr> in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

I want to calculate the sum of the 2nd `<td>` item in each of the rows and sum the total into my div.

My JS is as follows

```
$('.table tbody tr:gt(0)').each(function () {

var mixTotal = parseInt($(this).find('td:nth(2)').html());

// Add total to div 
$('.totals').text(mixTotal);
});
```

**DEMO HERE http://jsfiddle.net/5pnMh/1/**

My Html is a standard HTML table, which contains a `thead` `tbody` and `tfoot`.

I can't seem to get it to work. I can get each value but not sure how to add them.

Looking for some help

Comment: Since I can't tell from your wording what the total should be, what should the total be? Do you want the last row (in tfoot) included in the sum?

Comment: no I don't - that is why my code had tbody only in it. Why the negative vote??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var mixTotal = 0;
$('tbody tr').each(function () {
    mixTotal += parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),10);
});
$('.totals').html(mixTotal);
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/devlshone/5pnMh/4/)

Your last row of numbers will not be included in the TOTAL because it is a `<tfoot>`. Please also note that just because your first row is a `<thead>`, you may not leave out the `<tr></tr>` tags.

Answer (score 2):

I think is better store the result in variable and after loop append it to div.

```
// Set global var
var mixTotal = 0;
$('.table tbody tr').each(function () {
    // Just add the number
    mixTotal = mixTotal+parseInt($(this).find('td:nth-child(2)').html());
});
// And finally, add total to div 
$('.totals').text(mixTotal);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/5pnMh/3/

If you will replace `:nth(2)` to a `:nth-child(2)`, your code may partly works.

Comment: You left the radix out of parseInt.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to sum the values in the second column, try this:

```
var mixTotal = 0;
$('.table tbody tr').add('.table tfoot tr').each(function () {
    mixTotal += parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10);   
});
$('.totals').text(mixTotal); // Add total to div
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/5pnMh/8/)**

Comment: You are uselessly rewriting `.totals` html. Move it out of the `loop`.

Comment: Where does the OP ask to also include the `<tfoot>` row in his total?

Comment: @DevlshOne - where doesn't he?

Comment: @j08691 So, as long as you DON'T ask me to not hit you with a bus, it's ok?

Comment: @M1K1O - true. A little harsh with the 'uselessly', but updated as it's redundant.

Comment: @DevlshOne - uh, what? The OP doesn't specify that that row should be ignored does he?

Comment: @j08691 His initial code specifically says `tbody tr:gt(0)`. Nowhere does he include `tfoot`.

Comment: @DevlshOne - that's fine, but I'm going to make that assumption. If the OP doesn't want the row in tfoot he just needs to remove the `.add('.table tfoot tr')` from my code. I'm going by what the OP asked in the question, not the code he posted which he acknowledged doesn't work. BTW, why are you so concerned with my answer?

Answer (score 0):

use this code if you got decimal numbers

```
var mixTotal = 0;
$('tbody tr').each(function () {
    mixTotal += parseFloat($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),10);
});
$('.totals').html(mixTotal);
```

See **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/365kx/)**

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mixTotal = 0;
 $('#your_table_id tbody tr').each(function () {           
            mixTotal = mixTotal + (isNaN(parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(), 10)) ? 0 : parseInt($(this).find('td:eq(1)').text(),10))
        });
        
        $('.totals').html(mixTotal);

if u have both types of values like text or nan value
```